# CMS Made Simple - Set Variable to be Available across Templates

Tags: templates, variables, cmsmadesimple

Is it possible to create a custom variable in CMS Made Simple that could be set in one template and then this value would be available in another template for the same site?

Edit:
I forgot to add that the template I want to set the variable in is using a different domain, although it is the same site. This means I can't use cookies or session vars.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the smarty assign or capture system:

```
{assign var="foo" value="bar"}

{capture name="foo"}bar{/capture}
```

Please note that this depends on the order of the templates are executed. For example, in most scenarios, everything inside  is executed before everything inside  from the main template.